# How to keep radio button selected according to previously selected response using jquery or php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating an online quiz system, where i am taking questions along with there options from `getquestion.php` using ajax on `quiz.html`, i have added next and previous button on `quiz.html`, when user select an answer and hit next it goes to the second question, but when user hit previous button i want to show the previously selected option which user selected before hit next button. i tried but code is not working please help me i am new with this.

`quiz.html`

```
<div id='questionArea' style="position:absolute;top:30%;left:1%;"></div>
<button id='next' type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:1%;padding:5px;width:80px;background-color:silver;border:1px solid grey;color:white;border-radius:20%;cursor:pointer;">Next</button><button id='prev' type="submit" style='display: none;position:absolute;top:50%;left:10%;padding:5px;width:80px;background-color:silver;border:1px solid grey;color:white;border-radius:20%;cursor:pointer;'>Previous</button>
```

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var number = 0;
 $.post('getquestion.php', {number: number}, function(result){

        $('#questionArea').html(result);
    });

$('#next').click(function() {
number = number + 1;

    if (number => 1){
$('#prev').css('display','block');
}

    $.post('getquestion.php', {number: number}, function(result){

        $('#questionArea').html(result);
    });

});

$('#prev').click(function() {
number = number - 1;
    if (number < 1){
$('#prev').css('display','none');
}

    $.post('getquestion.php', {number: number}, function(result){

        $('#questionArea').html(result);
    }); 
});
});
```

`getquetion.php`

```
                if(isset($_POST['number'])){
            $number = $_POST['number'];
            }
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `questions`";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $qid = array();
            $question = array();
            $chA = array();
            $chB = array();
            $chC = array();
            $chD = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $qid[] = $row['question_id'];
            $question[] = $row['question'];
            $chA[] = $row['ansa'];
            $chB[] = $row['ansb'];
            $chC[] = $row['ansc'];
            $chD[] = $row['ansd'];
            $correct = $row['correct_ans'];
            }



            echo "<div id='question'>".$qid[$number].")"." ". $question[$number] . "</div>";
            echo "<input id='a' type='radio' name='a' value='" . $chA[$number] ."'> " . $chA[$number] . "<br>";
            echo "<input id='b' type='radio' name='a' value='" . $chB[$number] ."'> " . $chB[$number] . "<br>";
            echo "<input id='c' type='radio' name='a' value='" . $chC[$number] ."'> " . $chC[$number] . "<br>";
            echo "<input id='d' type='radio' name='a' value='" . $chD[$number] ."'> " . $chD[$number] . "<br>";




            ?>
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <script>
            var value;

            $("#a").click(function(){
                value = $(this).val();


            });
            $("#b").click(function(){
                value = $(this).val();

            });
            $("#c").click(function(){
                value = $(this).val();


            });
            $("#d").click(function(){
                value = $(this).val();


            });

            $('#prev').click(function(){
                if(value == "something that user selects before"){
                    $('#').prop("checked",true);
                }else{
                    $('#').prop("checked",false);
                }
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Well here's an idea, when you press back you can use `ajax` and `php` to get the last inserted id for the and then echo out those values. Then if he keeps going then you need to get the ID of the one before the last `lastID - 1` something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you could store answers in session for that question like

```
$_SESSION["Q3"] = 3;
```

and  then check if session is set and if yes make this

```
echo "<input id='d' type='radio' name='a' value='" . $chD[$number] ."'> " . $chD[$number] . "<br>";
```

into

```
echo "<input CHECKED id='d' type='radio' name='a' value='" . $chD[$number] ."'> " . $chD[$number] . "<br>";
```

this.

Comment: I tried it but using session for each que along with there answers, means i have 100 question and each is having 4 options. if i set session acc. to there question and answer the code is getting worse. Like if a user select que1 and any of 4 options, it will set session for que1 now i have to check for que2 that session is set for que1 but not for que2 so that user is able to set it accordingly. is it possible to do it with using array and jquery? actually i am not getting the logic.